# How do I pass user input from navbar (bootsrap) into my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Yelp API. I have a bootstrap navbar that I want the user to write in what city they would like the Yelp results to correspond to. But currently the user cannot type in their city of choice, only me as the programmer. Here is my controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

  def search
    parameters = { term: params[:term], limit: 16 }
    render json: Yelp.client.search('London', parameters)
  end
end
```

As you can see, if the user wants to go to London, I have to type "London" in my controller. But I want the user input from the navbar to take this responsibility.

Here is the code for my _navbar.html.erb:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Which city?">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search form should POST to an endpoint in your controller. You could have a "search" action and take the parameter from the URL. The form tag you have by default will try to push a query parameter, this would be the search term.

You are close.

Comment: Can you give me an example in the form and controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your form input needs a `name` attribute to send data so you can receive it in your `params` hash.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Which city?" name="search">
```

The form needs to know where to go as well

```
 <form action="/searches/search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
```

When you send the form now, you will get the result sent to your controller inside of your params hash.

You can then update the render to

```
Yelp.client.search(parmas[:search], parameters)
```

[Here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-http-requests) is an pretty good tutorial on how requests work.